# Modifying machine registers for AMD machines

Tags: amd-processor, msr

I was looking into modifying MSRs and PCI configuration registers on AMD machines. I know which bits to change etc by looking into this: http://amd-dev.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wordpress/media/2012/10/42301_15h_Mod_00h-0Fh_BKDG1.pdf

I tried using the rdmsr/wrmsr commands (msr-tools) but it doesn't really change anything for the AMD machines. How do I make changes to msrs and other registers on Linux?

Comment: I'd imagine you can only do this from kernel-space...

Comment: I agree, whats the best way to change anything in the kernel?